# How to find the presence of another class in a div/ul using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is how I have my "ul" written. As you can see there are two classes written in for the ul

```
<ul class="nav-second-level collapse">
</ul>
```

Now there may be another addition of a class to the same div like below

```
  <ul class="nav-second-level collapse in">
    </ul>
```

I need to check whether the class "in" is present in the "ul". How can I do that using jquery/javascript?

Comment: What have you tried? A quick [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+element+has+class) produces plenty of results.

Comment: [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) may help you!

Comment: you should go through this https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use `jQElement.hasClass();`

Without jQuery, you can use `element.className` or `element.classList`.

the first will produce a string like "nav-second-level collapse" and the second will produce an Array of strings ["nav-second-level", "collapse"].

And then, you can check if either the string or the array contains your class, with `.indexOf(yourClass)`

However, `classList` is more recent and you should check the [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

just check that class by

```
    var test = $(ul).hasClass( "in" );
```

this will return "true".

you can then put if condition

```
    Ex: if(test == true){}else{}
```